# Track gestures from service android

Tags: android, service, kotlin, gesture

I'm working on a UX testing app, which should track gestures silently (from a service, without intercepting events).

Here is my current code :

```
class TrackService : Service(), View.OnTouchListener {

private val DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures"
var mWindowManager: WindowManager? = null
var mDummyView: LinearLayout? = null

override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
}

override fun onCreate() {
    mWindowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    mDummyView = LinearLayout(this)
    val layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(1, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    mDummyView!!.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)
    mDummyView!!.setOnTouchListener(this)
    val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            1, /* width */
            1, /* height */
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT
    )
    params.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.TOP
    mWindowManager!!.addView(mDummyView, params)
    super.onCreate()
}

override fun onTouch(p0: View?, p1: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, p1.toString())
    return false
}
```

My problem is that this code just catches `ACTION_OUTSIDE`, and so does not let me identify `MotionEvent`.
I tried to modify my code in order to make `mDummyView` take all screen, but if I do it, the events are consumed by this View and are not transferred to the other Views (and apps).

Do someone know how I could track gestures without trapping them in my service?

Comment: Outside of a rooted device or custom ROM, this is not possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: As I'm not limited by hardware stuff, how could it be done on a rooted device ?

Comment: Personally, I have no idea, other than I would expect it to be possible.

Comment: Ok, I will wait for other paths so ;)
Oh, and I don't understand the problem with security. I can record the screen, and get coordinates of ACTION_OUTSIDE... So there is a lack of security here

Comment: The primary security problem comes when your app can see the input events *and* they get passed to the underlying app. That's the specific thing that you have discovered is not possible.

Comment: @girod_s It is a security problem for the same reason keyloggers are a security problem.

Comment: Try to extend View with and override `onTouchEvent` method, this will allow passing touch event to other views

Comment: @dimaRostipira, I can't do it, because I already extends Service